# Flutter ios db.execute("Create Table) does not work in onCreate

Tags: ios, flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

Hello everybody today I figured out that db.execute method of sqflite is not working when running my app on ios simulator I don't know why?
it gives me an error "no such a table" it seems that the code didn't create the tables in the database the code running in the onCreate method has no effect on the database and it is silent no error raised.
here is my code :

```
 Future<void> _initializeDatabase() async {
    if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux) {
      sqfliteFfiInit();
    }

    String documentFolder = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
//
    String path = kDebugMode
        ? "E:\\Flutter-Projects\\online_order_project"
        : documentFolder;

    String fileDatabase = "$path\\online_order_db.db";

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      String p = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!.path;

      fileDatabase = "$p\\online_order_db2.db";
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      String p = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;

      fileDatabase = pathlib.join(p, "online_order_db-ios");
    }

    DataManager._sqliteDatabase = await databaseFactoryFfi.openDatabase(
        fileDatabase,
        options: OpenDatabaseOptions(
            onUpgrade: _onUpgrade,
            onConfigure: _onConfigure,
            onCreate: _onCreate,
            version: 4));

    DataManager._appDatabase = _sqliteDatabase;
  }
_onConfigure(Database db) async {
    await db.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = off');

    print("DATABASE VERSION${await db.getVersion()}");
  }

  _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    try {
      String sql =
          await rootBundle.loadString('assets/files/shopping_card_db.sql');
      await db.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = off');

      await db.execute(sql);//===this line does not work (does not alter the database)

      await db.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = on');
    } catch (ex) {
      print(ex.toString());
    }
  }

  _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVer, int newVer) async {
    if (oldVer < newVer) {
      String sql =
          await rootBundle.loadString('assets/files/shopping_sql_ver3.sql');

      await db.execute(sql);
    }
  }
```

Here is shopping_card_db.sql located on assets/files:

```
--
-- File generated with SQLiteStudio v3.3.3 on Sun Aug 7 08:47:35 2022
--
-- Text encoding used: UTF-8
--
PRAGMA foreign_keys = off;




-- Table: tblorder
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblorder;

CREATE TABLE tblorder (
    id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    order_date      DATE,
    customer_id     INTEGER,
    user_id         INTEGER,
    status          BOOLEAN,
    total_amount    NUMERIC,
    order_number    INTEGER,
    discount_ratio  NUMERIC,
    discount_amount NUMERIC,
    net_total       NUMERIC,
    tax_total       NUMERIC,
    discount_total  NUMERIC,
    cashPaid        NUMERIC,
    invoice_number  VARCHAR (20),
    is_later        INTEGER (1)  DEFAULT (0) 
);


-- Table: category
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category;

CREATE TABLE category (
    id                  INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name_english        VARCHAR (70),
    name_arabic         VARCHAR (70),
    notes               VARCHAR (300),
    image_url           TEXT,
    category_order      INTEGER (3),
    package_no_of_items INTEGER (3) 
);


-- Table: customer
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer;

CREATE TABLE customer (
    id          INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    first_name  VARCHAR (50),
    last_name   VARCHAR (50),
    middle_name VARCHAR (50),
    email       VARCHAR (100),
    phone       VARCHAR (20),
    username    VARCHAR (20),
    password    VARCHAR (8),
    status      BOOLEAN
);


-- Table: order_detail
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS order_detail;

CREATE TABLE order_detail (
    id              INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    order_id        INTEGER      REFERENCES tblorder (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    amount          NUMERIC,
    quantity        INTEGER (3),
    product_id      VARCHAR (20),
    discount_amount NUMERIC,
    discount_ratio  NUMERIC,
    total_amount    NUMERIC,
    net_total       NUMERIC
);


-- Table: order_payment
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS order_payment;

CREATE TABLE order_payment (
    id              INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    order_id        INTEGER       REFERENCES tblorder (id),
    payment_type_id INTEGER,
    amount          REAL,
    payment_date    DATE,
    paid_by         VARCHAR (100),
    user_id         INTEGER
);


-- Table: payment_type
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS payment_type;

CREATE TABLE payment_type (
    id           INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name_english VARCHAR (100),
    name_arabic  VARCHAR (100),
    cache_type   INTEGER (1) 
);


-- Table: product
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;

CREATE TABLE product (
    id           VARCHAR (20)  PRIMARY KEY,
    name_english VARCHAR (150),
    category_id  INTEGER       REFERENCES category (id),
    image        BLOB,
    price        NUMERIC,
    image_url    TEXT,
    name_arabic  VARCHAR (150),
    unit_id      INTEGER,
    tax_ratio    INTEGER
);


-- Table: setting
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS setting;

CREATE TABLE setting (
    id           INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name_arabic  VARCHAR (255),
    name_english VARCHAR (255),
    ip           VARCHAR (20),
    port         INTEGER (3),
    path         VARCHAR (255),
    year         INTEGER (3),
    company      VARCHAR (20) 
);




-- Table: unit
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS unit;

CREATE TABLE unit (
    id           INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name_arabic  VARCHAR (150),
    name_english VARCHAR (150) 
);


-- Table: user
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;

CREATE TABLE user (
    id               INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    username         VARCHAR (20),
    password         VARCHAR (20),
    phone            VARCHAR (20),
    image            BLOB,
    username_arabic  VARCHAR (120),
    username_english VARCHAR (120) 
);



PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;
```

So when i run "Select * from setting" it give error :
"no such a table setting"
[image]